# Add a service in Angular customValidationservice not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I what to make a customvalidationService with a method that validates that the userName is not in use. However i need to include my userService to check that the user is not in use when I try to add the userService I get the following error << Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userService') >>

Here is my CustomValidationService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CustomValidationService {

  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ) { }
  userName(control: AbstractControl): { [Key: string]: any } | null {
    const userName: string = control.value;

    var employee: Employee = {
      //Some other fields ...
      "userName": userName
    }

    //This line is causing issue
   const userExists = this.userService.checkIfEmployeeUserNameExists(employee);

    if (!userExists) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return { 'userName': true };
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my userService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  public loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); // {1}
  public employees: Employee[];

  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) { }

      checkIfEmployeeUserNameExists(employee: Employee): Observable<boolean>  {
        return this.http.put<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'employees/isUserNameUnique', employee)
      }
   }
```

And here is where I make the call to the CustomValidationService in EmployeeDetailsComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-details',
  templateUrl: './employee-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-details.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    public translate: TranslateService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private typeService: UserTypeService,
    private menuService: MenuService,
    private _customValidation: CustomValidationService
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {

    const customValidation = new CustomValidationService(this.userService);

      this.userService.getEmployee(this.employeeId).subscribe(async result => {
        this.employee = await result;
        this.employeeDetailForm = new FormGroup({
          userName: new FormControl(this.employee.userName, [Validators.required, customValidation.userName])
        });
}
}
```

Comment: Query: Why have you used `async`-`await` within `getEmployee` subscription?

Comment: Good question I do not need it I removed it but it does not change the fact that the userService does not work in my CustomValidationService. :( But thank you for the advice.

Comment: The place where you're making call to `this.userService.getEmployee`. have you injected "UserService" within constructor?

Comment: @AakashGoplani I am not sure do you mean this code <<  constructor(private userService: UserService){ }  >> in my customValidationService?

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach Did you import the `userService` before injecting it in your constructor in the `customerValidationService`?

Here is a quick  [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x9qu69)

Comment: @skouch2022 you mean if I have this line import { UserService } from './employee.service'; in my CustomValidationService if so the answer is yes.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach Cool. Did you check out the demo?

Comment: @skouch2022 I have tried however I have (control: AbstractControl): { [Key: string]: any } | null {} where I want to use the service this seams to be causing the problem.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach Could you please temporarily make your `userName` function in the `CustomValidationService` to look like the `getUserName` function in `CustomerValidationService` in my demo? The error you are getting is saying that the `userService` is undefined. When we remove all the noise, then we can isolate issue and see what's going on.

Comment: @skouch2022 I think that I am already using userName function in CustomValidationService. I realise that maybe the last par of my question was not very clear I want to use the CustomValidationService inside a diffrent component to be exact the EmployeeDetailsComponent. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @JuniorCortenbach Yes, I understood that you want to use `CustomValidationService` inside the `EmployeeDetailsComponent`. In my [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x9qu69), I do exact same thing, but instead of `EmployeeDetailsComponent`, it's `AppComponent`. What I am asking is to change your `userName` function to look like `getUserName` function in my demo so we can fix this error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userService')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues here

1. the main reason you are seeing this is because you are passing a function without binding it. When you pass a function, 'this' is undefined. you have to `bind` it first

`customValidation.userName.bind(customValidation)`

this will get rid of the undefined error. However, ypur code will still not work as ypu think it will because...

2. you are using async opepration as sync validator which will simply not work. you should use it as async validator in which case validator function returns Observable or Promjse that resolves to either null, or validation errors. This is similar to what you have now yet very different.
   Async validators are passed as 3rd argument of FormControl ctor

Comment: Yes, you are right the .bind(customValidation) fixes the 'this' is undefined. In addtion you are right it still does not realy do want I want. How can I do this in my case? I what the validations to be immediate so as soon as he types a existing user I want to see the user exists error. Will this still work whit your proposal and if so can you show me how?

Comment: If you make it as asnych validator it will work as you require, it will hanvle observables/promises for you.